# Number of the binary strings without consecutive zeroes of a certain length correlates with Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: java, algorithm, fibonacci

I'm trying to develop algorithm which would determinate number of binary strings without consecutive zeroes of a certain length. I found solution, which is based on Fibonacci sequence. I don't understand, how the binary string, that ends at the 0 or 1 and not contains repeated 0's depends of Fibonnacci sequence. 
Can anybody explain it?

For example, for length 3 answer will be 5, because:

```
 000
 001
*010
*011
 100
*101
*110
*111
```

*Strings without consecutive zeroes

Comment: Are you asking about the number of ways to have a binary string of length n without any contiguous segment of 2 or more 0s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's Z(k) is number of valid binary strings, ending with 0. Denote such string `*0`

Let's O(k) is number of valid binary strings, ending with 1.  Denote such string `*1`

We can build `*0` with length `k+1` only with adding `0` to the end of `*1`, so

```
Z(k+1) = O(k)
```

We can build `*1` with length `k+1` adding `1` both to the end of any `*1`,  and to the end of any `*0`, so

```
O(k+1) = O(k) + Z(k)
```

Consider all valid strings with length (k+2)

```
F(k+2) = 
       Z(k+2) +      O(k+2)          = 
       O(k+1) +      O(k+1) + Z(k+1) = 
       O(k) + Z(k) + O(k+1) + Z(k+1) =
       F(k)        + F(k+1)
```

Do you see Fibonacci-like relation?

Comment: That's it, thank you very much, and sorry for late:)